# White box after clicking a Link

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

[image]

Hi, got some weird box coming out after clicking a link that has a scrollTo plugin.
How do i remove that effect?, it's popping when it's focused I think.

I tried `user-select: none` but still won't go away. Help is appreciated. Though in Chrome this doesn't show up and works cleanly. Ain't good on FF and IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

However, you might want to use a more specific selector - removing outlines from elements actually impedes accessibility.

Comment: yea found this too on normalize.css, was about to remove it completely but thanks for the tip i'll just point it to my nav

Answer (score 1):

```
a{
  outline: 0;
}

a::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0; 
}
```